# Migrating data from Firebird to CSV on OSX

Tags: export, firebird, csv, mac-os-x

I have a `.gdb` Firebird database file that I would like to partially transform to `.csv`. From the CLI tool, I'm able to do the following:

`CONNECT "/Users/jpmonette/Desktop/file.gdb";
OUTPUT /Users/jpmonette/Desktop/output.csv;
SELECT EMAIL,FIRSTNAME FROM ACCOUNT;`

This seems to be working as expected - outputting stdout to a file. However, I would like to know if there is a way to output the data in a easy to consume format (JSON? CSV? SQL dump?). I had a look at `fbexport` and `fbcopy`, but they both seem to be not available for OSX.

Any clue on how I could get around that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can concatenate output to CSV, like `select email || ',' || firstname from account` with column header turned off using `set heading`

Comment: It doesn't seem to behave well with line breaks, encoding and escaping the commas. Any other way that I could dump this data in a consumable format?

Comment: @jpmonette As far as I know there is no common agreed format for linebreaks in CSV. You might want to search for a tool that supports JDBC and exports to CSV.